# JS adding close button to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm a JS rookie, so be patient with me. I'm working on a website with a photo gallery where when you click on a picture it opens a modal. I've worked a free template to realise that.

However I've added a 'close' icon, but I don't know how to make it work. Can you please help me?

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){        
 $('li img').on('click',function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  var img = '<img src="' + src + '" class="img-responsive"/>';
  
  //start of new code new code
  var index = $(this).parent('li').index();   

  var html = '';
  html += '<span class="close" style=padding:5px;>X</span>';
  html += img;                
  html += '<div style="height:25px;clear:both;display:block;">';
  html += '<a class="controls next" href="'+ (index+2) + '">pros &raquo;</a>';
  html += '<a class="controls previous" href="' + (index) + '">&laquo; prec</a>';
  html += '</div>';
  
  $('#myModal').modal();
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
   $('#myModal .modal-body').html(html);
   //new code
   $('a.controls').trigger('click');
   $('span.close').trigger('click');
  })
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
   $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');
  });
    
   }); 
})  
         
$(document).on('click', 'a.controls', function(){
 var index = $(this).attr('href');
 var src = $('ul.row li:nth-child('+ index +') img').attr('src');             
 
 $('.modal-body img').attr('src', src);
 
 var newPrevIndex = parseInt(index) - 1; 
 var newNextIndex = parseInt(newPrevIndex) + 2; 
 
 if($(this).hasClass('previous')){               
  $(this).attr('href', newPrevIndex); 
  $('a.next').attr('href', newNextIndex);
 }else{
  $(this).attr('href', newNextIndex); 
  $('a.previous').attr('href', newPrevIndex);
 }
 
 var total = $('ul.row li').length + 1; 
 //hide next button
 if(total === newNextIndex){
  $('a.next').hide();
 }else{
  $('a.next').show()
 }            
 //hide previous button
 if(newPrevIndex === 0){
  $('a.previous').hide();
 }else{
  $('a.previous').show()
 }
 
 
 return false;
});
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: If you could post a JSBin or JSFiddle of your code you will get a solution in no time. :)

Comment: I was bored so i made [This](http://jsbin.com/sizuzas/edit?html,js,output). If you find it useful I'll provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `event` delegation technique to attach `click` handler to your close element. This is because you are generating your modal's DOM via script i.e. its a dynamically generated HTML. You can try below code instead of your code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", function(){
    // call 'close' method on nearest kendoWindow
    $(this).closest("[data-role=window]").data("kendoWindow").close();
    // the above is equivalent to:
    //$(this).closest(".k-window-content").data("kendoWindow").close();
});
```

Comment: Found the mistake! There was another css class called "close" which created a conflict... Silly me. Now your method works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

hay use framework for simplifier your job   bro

from w3school
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>




// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}






<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
Step 2) Add CSS:

Example
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I've checked that, but I don't know how to apply it to my case. Check the JS code I've provided and see if you understand how to do that :-)